# Zassenhaus formula exponents

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

found Zassenhaus formula for noncommutative $X,Y$
$$e^{t(X+Y)}= e^{tX}~  e^{tY} ~e^{-\frac{t^2}{2} [X,Y]} ~
e^{\frac{t^3}{6}(2[Y,[X,Y]]+ [X,[X,Y]] )} ~
e^{\frac{-t^4}{24}([[[X,Y],X],X] + 3[[[X,Y],X],Y] + 3[[[X,Y],Y],Y]) } \cdots$$
Please, how could I getexponents of higher order in Zassenhaus formula?

Answer (score 1):

Check the reference
F. Casas, A. Murua, M. Nadinic, "Efficient computation of the Zassenhaus formula", Computer Physics Communications 183 (2012), 2386-2391.
It contains even a mathematica code for generating all the terms in the formula

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0389